# passing instance of inherited class after init (Python 2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, init

I am trying to access the object of `class b` (self.variable) inside another `class a`, after `class b` has been inherited by `class c` and calls an instance of `class a`. I don't know how to access the instance of `class b` that was created during the inheritance init. Additionally, a needs to inherit from `class k`.

Optimal would be if I could access `self.variable` inside `class a` and further pass it on without explicitly referring to the instance of `class b` (namely, just calling it with `self.variable` instead of `b.variable`) and without changing the values I already assigned to the variables in `class c` (so no re-initializing it)

I'd appreciate any help, I've been at this for hours.

```
class k(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class b(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = 1

class c(b):
    def __init__(self):
        b.__init__(self)# b is inherited from & initialized
        # alternative for inheritance
        #super(c,self).__init__()
        print("init(): " + str(self.variable))
    def run(self):
        self.variable = 2
        print("run(): " + str(self.variable))
        a()# here I need to pass the instance of b

class a(k):
    def __init__(self):
        k.__init__(self)# a() needs to inherit from k()
        # ERROR: cannot access variables of b()
        print("a(): " + str(self.variable))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c().run()
```

Comment: `class a` has no knowledge of `class b` or `class c`, and therefore cannot access their attributes. As you are using python 2, `class k` should inherit from `object` or be an old style class.

Comment: yes, I know. I don't know how I can get the knowledge to `a`, and class k I cannot access (but ok, for this example I can change it and think about the implications later)

Comment: could someone tell me what I did wrong in the post? I really tried to do it right and then I get a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out how to do it.
If passing the instance is enough, this would work:

```
class k(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class b(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bb = self.bb()
    class bb:
        def __init__(self):
            self.variable = 1

class c(b):
    def __init__(self):
        b.__init__(self)# b is inherited from & initialized
        # alternative for inheritance
        #super(c,self).__init__()
        print("init(): " + str(self.bb.variable))
    def run(self):
        self.bb.variable = 99
        print("run(): " + str(self.bb.variable))
        a(self)# pass instance of b

class a(k):
    def __init__(self, bInstance):
        k.__init__(self)# a() needs to inherit from k()
        print("a(): " + str(bInstance.bb.variable))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    c().run()
```

As I understand it, if I want to get there via self I'd need `class a` to inherit from `class c` and `class c` inherits and initializes `class b`, the call at the end is just `a()` (which does what I need it to do, since a inherits everything I need):

```
class k(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class b(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bb = self.bb()
    class bb:
        def __init__(self):
            self.variable = 1

class c(b):
    def __init__(self):
        b.__init__(self)# b is inherited from & initialized
        # alternative for inheritance
        #super(c,self).__init__()
        print("init(): " + str(self.bb.variable))
    def run(self):
        self.bb.variable = 99
        print("run(): " + str(self.bb.variable))


class a(k,c):
    def __init__(self):
        k.__init__(self)# a() needs to inherit from k()
        c.__init__(self)
        print("a(): " + str(self.bb.variable))

        self.run()
        print("a() #2: " + str(self.bb.variable))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    a()
```